# Simple permutations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In how many ways can the letters of the word
E L E E M O S Y N A R Y
be arranged so that the S is always immediately followed
by a Y ?
the answer was 11*10!/3! how is that the answer?

Is it because of there are a minimum of 10 letters to be combined and 3 possible entries of the s and y?

Comment: Glue the S and Y together into one object, so it's $\frac{11!}{3!}$ because you have 11 objects with 3 repeats

Comment: strangely enough the answer written 11*10!/3! is actually the text book answer but the logic is bothering me to no end!

Answer (score 1):

I would use David Quinn's method, but since the logic of the book answer is bothering you, let me explain.

Leaving aside the glued together $(SY)$, there are 10 letters with 3 repeats, which can be permuted in $\dfrac{10!}{3!}$ ways.

Now, the $(SY)$ can be inserted into any of the **11 gaps (including ends)** of the 10 other letters,

hence $11*10!/3!$

But as I said, much simpler to use the $11!/3!$ logic.

Answer (score 0):

We see that we have $3 E$ 's, $2S$ 's, $2Y$ 's and all the other letters appear once. If we don't take account the restriction all the possible permutations are:
$$\frac{12!}{3!\cdot 2!\cdot  2!\cdot \underbrace{1!\cdots 1!}_{5 \text{ times }}}.$$

Now, consider the string $"YS"$ as one letter. Then we have $11$ letters: $3E'S$ and all the other letters appear once. So, all the possible permutations are:
$$\frac{11!}{3!\cdot\underbrace{1!\cdots 1!}_{8 \text{ times}}}=\frac{11!}{3!}$$